# Wrong parameters passed using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using the following rules I would to match URLs of the pattern *domain.com/Controller/Action*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Controller=$1&Action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Controller=$1&Action=Index [L]
```

When I call *domain.com/Foo/Bar* though the request variables are

```
Array ( [Controller] => index.php [Action] => Index )
```

What did I wrong here? Moreover how could I match no parameters at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add rewrite conditions to avoid rewriting for real file/directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Controller=$1&Action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Controller=$1&Action=Index [L,QSA]
```